# In Loopback.js, how to respond to a remote method with an empty body if it has a return argument?

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop

If I have a remote method like this:

```
Command.remoteMethod('invoke', {
  http: {verb: 'post', status: 200, source: 'body'},
  returns: {arg: "text", type: "string"}
});
```

Sometimes we need to respond with the `text` argument and sometimes with a completely empty body. In the remote method code, I have something like this:

```
Command.invoke = callback => {
  // ...

  if (error) {
    callback(null, 'There was an error');
  } else {
    callback(null);
  }
}
```

The problem is, in the `else` branch, the body is never empty. I've also tried:  `callback(null, null)` and `callback(null, '')`.

Is there a way to achieve this? Or do I need to implement a remote hook to  manually modify the response to get what I'm after?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best way is to use the after remote function

if no content then you can add

```
ctx.res.statusCode = 204
ctx.res.end(null);
```

Comment: Calling `ctx.res.end()` means calling `next()` afterwards would be a no op, correct?

Answer (score 0):

When you define a `returns` block in model.js, it means your remote method has a response body.

For your situation you can remove result in remote hooks.

```
Command.afterRemote("invoke", function(ctx, instance, next){
        //check if you want return text or nothing
        //if nothing so set result to null, otherwise just call next()
        ctx.result = null;
        next();
    });
```

Comment: This was still providing a non-empty response